# Use showModalDialog or jQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery, html, dialog, intranet

When developing an intranet application where the target browser is IE only (IE6 - horrible I know) is there any reason that we shouldn’t use the `showModalDialog()` feature of IE to display dialog windows?

My colleague prefers using `showModalDialog()` but I prefer using a jQuery plug-in such as FancyBox, FaceBox or ThickBox instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would avoid showModalDialog just because at some stage in the future IE6 will be depreciated and you will have to go back and fix it all. I know some large organisations are slow, but do you think they will still be using IE6 in 2 or 3 years?

On the other hand, if it is a consulting gig, do it this way and then in 3 years time charge them again to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

My opinion is that `window.showModalDialog()` will not be deprecated as it is present in most major browsers and works perfect in all of them except Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you are doing, but the plugins you listed are not really the equivalent of a dialog window. They are more for a nice/fancy display of photos and content.

I would recommend with going with something non proprietary because your company can't stay on IE6 forever (Though it seems like it some times!).

I would also recommend looking into the [jQuery UI](http://ui.jquery.com) library and using their [Dialog widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) to provide a rich user experience.